# styles dont connect when loading local server

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, node.js-connect

my dir looks like that :

```
|-project
   -gulpfile.js  
   |-build
     -index.html
     |-js
       -app.min.js
       -vendors.min.js
     |-styles
       -all.css
       -vendors.min.css
```

i inject the css and js files with this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('index',function () {
return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['**/vendors.min.css','**/vendors.min.js','**/app.min.js','**/all.css'], {read: false})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    .pipe(livereload());
})
```

i set up a local server with node.js,when i do the request , the html file loads up,but the .js and .css files dont connect for some reason.Although when i check page's source code at output their paths are written in.

```
 <!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/styles/vendors.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/styles/all.css">
<!-- endinject -->
```

when i hover on one of them it shows :

```
 http://localhost:5000/build/styles/all.css
```

i use this task for setting the server :

```
gulp.task('connect', function() {
 connect.server({
   root: 'build',
   livereload: true,
    port: 5000
 });
});
```

**EDIT**

any recommendation about how to make it on hovering look like

```
localhost:5000/styles/all.css
```

Answer (score 0):

If the build folder is the root of the server, you shouldn't be including it in the path of the js and css files. This is failing because you are trying to reference a build folder inside the build folder.

Change your injection of css to the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendors.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/all.css">
```

Comment: The path to your css and js file must be relative to the file requesting them. As they are called from your index.html you need to change the href path as I have mentioned above

Comment: `.pipe(inject(gulp.src(['styles/all.css'], {read: false}), {relative: true} ))`
this code,doesnt inject anything

Comment: i tried even connecting it like that ` http://localhost:5000/styles/all.css` , when i run it in browser,it opens the css file,but still doesnt injects it